# Outer join Spark dataframe with non-identical join column and then merge join column

Tags: python, join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have the following dataframes in pySpark:

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(name='john', age=50), Row(name='james', age=25)])
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(name='john', weight=150), Row(name='mike', weight=115)])
df3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(name='john', age=50, weight=150), Row(name='james', age=25, weight=None), Row(name='mike', age=None, weight=115)])
```

Now suppose I want to create `df3` from joining/merging `df1` and `df2`.

I tried doing

```
df1.join(df2, df1.name == df2.name, 'outer')
```

This doesn't quite work exactly because it produces two name columns. I need to then somehow combine the two name columns so that missing names from one name column are filled in by the missing name from the other name column.

How would I do that? Or is there a better way to create `df3` from `df1` and `df2`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`coallesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) function which returns the first not-null argument.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

df1 = df1.alias("df1")
df2 = df2.alias("df2")

(df1.join(df2, df1.name == df2.name, 'outer')
  .withColumn("name_", coalesce("df1.name", "df2.name"))
  .drop("name")
  .withColumnRenamed("name_", "name"))
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a little late, but there is a simpler solution if someone needs it. Just a simple change from original poster's solution:

```
df1.join(df2, 'name', 'outer')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, ['name'], 'outer')
```

Joining in this way will prevent the duplication of the name column. https://kb.databricks.com/data/join-two-dataframes-duplicated-columns.html