# Generic coalesce of multiple columns in join pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks, coalesce

I have to merge many spark DataFrames. After the merge, I want to perform a coalesce between multiple columns with the same names.

I was able to create a minimal example following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165080/outer-join-spark-dataframe-with-non-identical-join-column-and-then-merge-join-co).

However, I need a more generic piece of code to support: a set of variables to coalesce (in the example `set_vars = set(('var1','var2'))`), and multiple join keys (in the example `join_keys = set(('id'))`).

Is there a less verbose (more generic) way to obtain this result in `pyspark`?

```
df1 =  spark.createDataFrame([ 
        ( 1, None ,  "aa"),
        ( 2 , "a", None ),
        ( 3 , "b",  None),
        ( 4 , "h",  None),],
        "id int, var1 string, var2 string",
       )

df2 =  spark.createDataFrame([ 
        ( 1, "f" ,  "Ba"),
        ( 2 , "a", "bb" ),
        ( 3 , "b",  None),],
        "id int, var1 string, var2 string",
       )

df1 = df1.alias("df1")
df2 = df2.alias("df2")

df3 = df1.join(df2, df1.id == df2.id, how='left').withColumn("var1_", coalesce("df1.var1", "df2.var1")).drop("var1").withColumnRenamed("var1_", "var1").withColumn("var2_", coalesce("df1.var2", "df2.var2")).drop("var2").withColumnRenamed("var2_", "var2")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can avoid duplicate columns by passing columns as a list to join method instead of writing joining condition, refer this [link](https://kb.databricks.com/data/join-two-dataframes-duplicated-columns.html).
But here there are some common columns which are not required for joining condition. we can use for loop to generalize your code.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

df1 =  spark.createDataFrame([
        ( 1, None ,  "aa"),
        ( 2 , "a", None ),
        ( 3 , "b",  None),
        ( 4 , "h",  None),],
        "id int, var1 string, var2 string",
       )

df2 =  spark.createDataFrame([
        ( 1, "f" ,  "Ba"),
        ( 2 , "a", "bb" ),
        ( 3 , "b",  None),],
        "id int, var1 string, var2 string",
       )

df1 = df1.alias("df1")
df2 = df2.alias("df2")

key_columns = ["id"]
# Get common columns between 2 dataframes excluding columns-
# -which are being used in joining conditions
other_common_columns = set(df1.columns).intersection(set(df2.columns))\
.difference(set(key_columns))

outputDF = df1.join(df2, key_columns, how='left')

for i in other_common_columns:
    outputDF = outputDF.withColumn(f"{i}_", coalesce(f"df1.{i}", f"df2.{i}"))\
.drop(i).withColumnRenamed(f"{i}_", i)

outputDF.show()

+---+----+----+
| id|var2|var1|
+---+----+----+
|  1|  aa|   f|
|  3|null|   b|
|  4|null|   h|
|  2|  bb|   a|
+---+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mohana, I wanted to include all in the same step, but the for solution is quite elegant too.